# Xcode: Breakpoints stopped working

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

I have a static lib and an Mac app that links to it. The debug build uses DWARF as debug info. I had been using the static lib project to attach to the app under Xcode4.2 and the breakpoints were working.

Recently I upgraded to Xcode4.4 and I don't deny that there could be other environment changes that I'm not aware of. Now I can't hit the breakpoints anymore.

I rebuilt my lib and also rebuilt my app against the lib.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer it myself:

According to Apple engineer on Xcode mailing list. This is an Xcode bug and I'll file a bug soon.

Currently there is a workaround, quote from the Apple engineer:

> I think we were still using gdb in Xcode 4.2. So in Xcode 4.4, you can workaround it by switching from lldb back to gdb in the Scheme Editor. If this workaround works, you have to file a bug because we are going to deprecate gdb soon.